# Getting the dimensions of a View on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, view, storyboard, width

I need to initialize an UIPicker inside a View fitting the size. It should fill the view and this view is from a storyboard.

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
```

It only works well on iPhone Retina 4 inch device. For others resolutions, the picker is bigger than the view and not shown full.

Please, anyone knows where is the problem ? I'm not using auto-layout, only storyboard.

Comment: Superview instrad of view?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the differing sizes between devices? The problem is unclear from your description.